# кроссдоменный запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Помогите с запросом что я делаю не так:

```js
// (1)
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

var xhr = new XHR();

// (2) запрос на другой домен :)
xhr.open('GET', 'https://clients1.google.com/complete/search?q=asd&client=translate-web&ds=translate&hl=zh&requiredfields=tl%3Aru&callback=_callbacks____2jb907enn', true);

xhr.onload = function() {
  alert( this.responseText );
}

xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert( 'Ошибка ' + this.status );
}

xhr.send();
```

почему кроссдоменный запрос возвращает ошибку, и как будет правильным?

Comment: правильно - это если сервер возвращает заголовки с разрешением. В данном случае видимо гугл этого не делает

Comment: А есть ли какой то обход?

Comment: писать запрос с сервера..... но емнип гугл транслейт в любом случае не даст инфу из-за меняющегося токена...

Comment: Ну ладно, можете показать любой другой который получится? потому что столько доменов я не проверил все возвращает ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var XHR = function() {
    try {
      return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (ee) {}
    }
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
      return new XMLHttpRequest();

    }
  },
  xhr = XHR();
xhr.open("GET", "https://vk-blocked.000webhostapp.com/stackoverflow.php", true); //открваем xhr
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //создаём заголовок

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText); //вводим результат в консоль
    }
  }
};
xhr.send(null); //отправляем запрос
/*если нужно, могу дать функцию ajax, где уже всё упорядочено*/
```